# Angular 2 trigger element on click

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

[image]

So I have the following list, now I want when the clock is clicked to trigger a different element `(<ion-datetime> in this case)`, I know I need to put a click event on that clock but I don't know how to trigger the hidden element.

My Code:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>
    Working days
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let work_day of working_days;let i = index">
    <ion-label>{{work_day}}   
  <ion-icon name="clock" style="position:absolute;right:0px" (click)="trigger(child)"></ion-icon>
   <ion-datetime #child style="position:absolute;right:-99999999px" displayFormat="HH:MM" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime></ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Component**

```
working_days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];

constructor(){

}

trigger(value){
    value.trigger('click');
}
```

But this doesn't work, I'm new to ionic so any help is appreciated

Comment: So, are you trying to trigger the `<ion-checkbox>`?

Comment: No, that <ion-datetime

Comment: You code doesn't show any `(click)` event on `<ion-datetime>`... What would clicking on it do?

Comment: @GabrielLovetro please refresh, stackoverflow didn't display the whole code, will show up a modal with datetime https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/, I just want when someone click on the click to trigger a click on <ion-datetime>

Comment: Oh, I see - my mistake! I never tried to trigger a click like that before, but I have tried using jquery in the past and it is kind of simple (but not very good performance-wise, since it uses jquery and I don't think jqlite has that method).

Comment: I tried something with the code you have written. There's just 1 drawback I am observing here. Both, checkbox and <ion-datetime> seems to get the clickable area of entire item. Try removing the `style=".."` of <ion-datetime> and you will get it. So either check-box action can be taken place or the datetime picker action. Not both. I am afraid you might have to use something else than ion-item. Will try something with simple div layout and let you know.